# having difficulty inserting an array of subrecords using $push, getting internal server error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following record that I am trying to create in my database:

```
{
    "userid":
    "songs":[
         {
              "title":
              "artist":
         }
         {
              "title":
              "artist":
         }
    ]

}
```

There can be multiple songs under one user. I am unsure of the proper syntax to insert a record with multiple subrecords.I tried using:

```
Links.insert({userid: "user1", $push: {songs: {"song1","artist1"}}});
```

I tried using another alternative which is to create the record with only userid field first and then make updates to push songs into the record. However, I get the following error when I do the following:

```
Links.update({_id: Links.findOne({userid: "user1"})._id, $push: {songs:{"song1","artist1"}}});
```

Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]

I am confused, since I am using the _id field to update the records. Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mongo queries are wrong. These should work (untested):

**Insert**

```
Links.insert({ 
    userid : "user1", 
    songs : [ 
        { title : "song1", artist : "artist" }, 
        ... 
    ] 
});
```

You don't need to push the array in the insert command.

**Update**

```
Links.update({
    _id : Links.findOne({ userid : "user1" })._id
},
{
    "$push" : { title : "song1", artist : "artist" }
});
```

Note the Update query has two objects passed to it, one is the `selector`, the second is the `modifier` to apply.

See http://docs.meteor.com/#selectors